# Issues with relationship in SQLAlchemy in Flask

Tags: postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I am trying to create an application where a user logs in and can create a personal toolbox from a list of available tools.  I am having trouble with my database and I'm sure I'm not understanding the relationship setup correctly.  When I do a flask db migrate I get the error below:

```
INFO  [alembic.ddl.postgresql] Detected sequence named 'tool_tool_id_seq' as owned by integer column 'tool(tool_id)', assuming SERIAL and omitting
```

Below is an image of my ERD diagram as I envisioned it.  I certainly am open to suggestions if anyone has better ideas.  Each user can have a toolbox and each toolbox can have many tools.  A tool can have 1 of its quantity in each toolbox.

[image: ERD diagram of database schema]

Comment: Could you share your code for your database? It might be useful to see what you are currently doing

Comment: https://github.com/ag4sm/Toolbox/blob/b481e6320eda2ed8c9057f886b6195c4acd7f5f7/app/models.py is the link to the file on my Github repo.